# BizTalk Server Configuration failing to create group

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm trying to configure a BizTalk server in BizTalk Server 2013 R2. I'm using Windows 10 and a local DB. 
I can create the Enterprise SSO and the Business Rule Engine but not the BizTalk Server Group and the BizTalk Runtime.

It gives me the following error:

> Failed to read "Software\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\3.0\Administration" from the registry.
>       The network path was not found.

I've tried everything I could imagine, any ideas as why I can't create the group?

EDIT: After trying everything I could imagine, the problem was in the name of my machine that was too big. Because of that, BizTalk could not write in the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything I've searched on the web, I finally managed to solved the problem. 
Because my **machine name was too long** (15 characters), BizTalk could not edit the registry. After **changing it to 4 characters long**, I solved the problem and I was able configure the server.

Answer (score 3):

**BizTalk Server 2013 R2 is not supported on Windows 10.**

You can look this up in the official BizTalk Server documentation, which you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697.aspx

Supported for BizTalk Server 2013 R2 are: Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 SP1.

Windows 10 is not supported.

Comment: I've read that too, but one of my co-workers is currently running it on Windows 10. Could it be because of user permissions? I've tried some possible solutions, but none of them seems to solve the issue.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, just wanted to make it clear that it is, in fact, unsupported. It could be that any new update/hotfix breaks compatibility with Windows 10, so in my opinion I would not bother trying to get it to work on Windows 10. Instead, you might spin up a VM with a supported platform to install it.