# Is BizTalk Server 2010 supported by Windows 10?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm unable to find anywhere online where it states that BizTalk Server 2010 is supported/not supported fully by Windows 10.

Comment: This lists the supported operating systems for various version of BizTalk https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/926628  If the operating system is not listed as is the case with Windows 10, then it is not supported by any version of BizTalk

Comment: This article has not been updated since 02/13/2015, which was prior to the windows 10 release date.

Comment: And they have not updated it to include Windows 10, which means it is not supported unless you get it in writing from them that it is.   BizTalk 2013 R2 came out after and it also does not list it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697.aspx#Software Requirements

Comment: Hi Dijkgraaf, you should add this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not even BizTalk 2013 R2 is **supported** on Windows 10 as can be seen at   [Summary of 64-bit support, operating systems and SQL Server versions supported by BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/926628) and also
[Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2013 and 2013 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697.aspx#Software) as it is not listed on either page as a supported operating system.

There is a related question about BizTalk 2013 R2 and windows 10 called [BizTalk Server Configuration failing to create group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141641/biztalk-server-configuration-failing-to-create-group/39144466).  The conclusion for that is, yes you can run BizTalk 2013 R2 on Windows 10, but as per a answer and comments there it probably will not be supported by Microsoft for a Production environment and could break with updates and patches applied to the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, not directly but that shouldn't matter because running BizTalk Server on any client OS is never the best option.

**Yes**, you can run BizTalk Server 2010 in a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM using Client Hyper-V.  You need Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise but this would be the best way to do it even if the client OS supported it directly.